# Apache2 error code line 6 config

Tags: apache, ubuntu, error-handling, apache2

sudo service apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2                                         [fail]
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
AH00526: Syntax error on line 6 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf:
Invalid command 'sudo', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.

Honestly im really bad with code i am watching a tutorial on how to set up a website and i installed apache into my droplet but this happens when i try and restart please help

Comment: check line 6 on your dir.conf coz that's causing the issue.

Comment: the file /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf should only have the below in it for default. <IfModule mod_dir.c>

          DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm

</IfModule>